# How do I create a middleware that can read cookie in Actix Web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am setting data in a httpOnly cookie, this means that the javascript cannot directly interact with it, but on each request it is sent to the backend.

The content of the cookie is used for authorization purposes. Now I can include logic in every handler to extract the content of the cookie but I thought that will be tedious.

So I was thinking to extract the logic to get the cookie value and perform the authorization logic in a middleware. But unfortunately I have not been able to find out.

The closes I found is based off using actix_session but that does not fit my bill because it will still involve injecting Session into every handler, and then perform the authorization checks. I'll the handlers don't contain this logic and hence why i will love to put it in a middleware.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: actix-web-httpauth [documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web-httpauth/latest/actix_web_httpauth/middleware/struct.HttpAuthentication.html)?

Comment: @JishanShaikh no, that does not touch on reading cookies

Answer (score 1):

Pass an `actix_web::dev::ServiceRequest` parameter and get cookie from `.cookie` should read the cookie data:

```rust
use actix_web::{dev, web, Appstate, HttpResponse};
use actix_web::web::Data;
use futures::future::{ok, Ready};

async fn auth_middleware(req: dev::ServiceRequest, srv: web::Data<actix_web::AppState>) -> Result<dev::ServiceResponse, actix_web::Error> {
    let cookie_value = req
        .cookie("name-of-cookie")
        .map(|cookie| cookie.value().to_owned())
        .ok_or_else(|| HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish())?;

    if !is_authorized(&cookie_value) {
        return Err(HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish().into());
    }

    // authorized ? continue to the next middleware/handler
    let fut = srv
        .get_ref()
        .clone()
        .call(req)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(e.to_string()))?;
    Ok(fut)
}

fn is_authorized(cookie_value: &str) -> bool {
    // Authorization logic here
    true
}

let app_state = AppState { /* ... */ };
let app = App::new()
    .data(AppState {})
    .app_data(Data::new(app_state.clone()))
    .wrap_fn(auth_middleware) 
    .service(/* actix-web services */);
```

Comment: I get the error web::Data<actix_web::AppState>) not found in `actix_web` any idea how to fix?

Comment: That is because we have not initialized Data while initializing `app`. Edit: updated the snippet.